Index a column I lookup records by?
I have a hash string that I lookup my records by. it's 10 characters long, for example ghg65f54r3.
Should I index this column?

Yes, assuming it is not already a key.

Depends on a few things. Are you searching for exact matches, or ranges, or substrings? How many rows in the table? What's the cardinality of the column?
